# Cannot import cx_Oracle, have already installed all dependencies

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I get the following error when trying to import cx_Oracle in Python on CentOS:

```
ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle
```

I have already done the following:

1. pip install cx_Oracle. Proof:

   ```
   $ pip freeze | grep cx-Oracle
   cx-Oracle==6.4.1
   ```
2. Installed Instant Client Basic and Instanc Client SDK for Oracle on Linux
3. Executed the following commands:

   ```
   export ORACLE_HOME=/my/absolute/path/to/oreclient_install_dir/instantclient_18_3
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME
   ```
4. Created a symlink:

   ```
   cd $ORACLE_HOME 
   ln -s libclntsh.so.11.1 libclntsh.so
   ```

And yet even after all of this, I still can't import cx_Oracle in Python.

I installed Instant Client in a directory like so:

```
/oreclient_install_dir/instantclient_18_3
```

Comment: Maybe difference between `cx_Oracle` and `cx-Oracle`?

Comment: @lojza doing `import cx-Oracle` gives a syntax error on the '-' character

Comment: Can you show the contents of your instant client installation directory? You shouldn't need to create the symbolic link as the unzip now does it for you. You also shouldn't set the environment variable ORACLE_HOME. What error are you getting?

Comment: Do you have more than one version of Python installed?